# Javascript/Jquery Change Select list to Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list of options that I would like to change to clickable radio buttons.

Here is my select list:

```
<select id="VariationGroup44" class="select" name="dlVariationGroup44">
<option value="Select Color"> Select Color </option>
<option selected="selected" value="1"> Black </option>
<option value="2"> Red </option>
<option value="3"> Green </option>
<option value="4"> Blue </option>
</select>
```

I've successfully converted this into a UL, but the options were no longer clickable which is why I thought radio buttons would work better. All suggestions are welcomed and very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Workflow:**

1. Iterate over the options.
2. Take what you need
3. Build new checkboxes.
4. Append them to an element.

**The Code:**

```
$('#VariationGroup44 option').each(function(i,obj){
  $('<li><input type="radio" name="chkOpt'+i+'" value="'+$(obj).val()+'"/><label for="chkOpt'+i+'"> '+$(this).text()+'</label></li>').appendTo('ul');
});
```

[The working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2fSCE/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceSelect(select) {
  var opts = $(select).find('option');
  var name = $(select).attr('name');
  var id = $(select).attr('id');
  var list = [];
  opts.each(function() {
    list.push(
      '<li>'+
        '<label>'+
          '<input type="radio" name="'+ name +'">'+ 
          $(this).text()
        '</label>'+
      '</li>'
    );
  });
  $(select).replaceWith('<ul id="'+ id +'">'+ list.join('') +'</ul>');
}

// Usage
replaceSelect('#VariationGroup44');
```